# List of all possible SoapServer Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, soap

Are any/all of the exceptions a PHP [SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php) might throw documented anywhere?  (meaning the built is native PHP implementation of a SoapServer, not a third part PHP based implementation)

If not, is it possible to extract the possible exceptions using some sort of reflection?  If so, where would one start with that?

Also, is it possible to examine the PHP source to determine what exceptions the built in object might throw?  If so, where would one start with that?

Comment: *(source)* http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/soap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only exception specific to the SOAP extension is [SoapFault](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapfault.php).
There are two exceptions [built in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php) to the language.
The other built in exceptions are in [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php).

As @Gordon mentioned, you can see the source at http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/soap/.  Search for exception in soap.c to start.